# SQL: compare multiple tables with common many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite, many-to-many

two material Tables:

```
MaterialA
ID  Name
------------
1   Steel
2   Wood
3   Concrete
4   Gold
```

and

```
MaterialB
ID  Name
------------
1   Oil
2   Glass
3   Copper
4   Water
```

and a table with some notes:

```
Note
ID  Property
------------
1   hard
2   liquid
3   flammable
4   heavy
5   metal
6   lighter than water
```

so all materials can have zero or all notes (many-to-many relationship).
therefore the table attribution:

```
Attribution
ID  Table   Mat_ID  Note_ID
---------------------------
1   A       1       1
2   A       1       4
3   A       1       5
4   A       2       3
5   A       2       6
6   A       3       1
7   A       4       4
8   A       4       5
9   B       1       2
10  B       1       3
11  B       1       6
12  B       2       1
13  B       3       4
14  B       3       5
15  B       4       2
```

just for a better view, the material tables with note-id's:

```
MaterialA
ID  Name        Notes
---------------------
1   Steel       1, 4, 5
2   Wood        3, 6
3   Concrete    1
4   Gold        4, 5
```

and

```
MaterialB
ID  Name        Notes
---------------------
1   Oil         2, 3, 6
2   Glass       1
3   Copper      4, 5
4   Water       2
```

how is the query to get materials from MaterialA which have the same notes like any material in MaterialB.
So the result should be:

```
Result
ID  Name
------------
3   Concrete
4   Gold
```

I'm using SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
select MaterialA.ID, MaterialA.Name
from (
    select "Table", mat_ID, group_concat(Note_ID) notes from Attribution where "Table"='A' group by "Table", mat_ID ) ta
join (
    select "Table", mat_ID, group_concat(Note_ID) notes from Attribution where "Table"='B' group by "Table", mat_ID )tb on ta.notes=tb.notes 
join MaterialA on ta.mat_id=MaterialA.ID
```

if you need order by in Attribution table, you must first do your order by and then use group_concat(). for example:

```
select MaterialA.ID, MaterialA.Name
from (
    select "Table", mat_ID, group_concat(Note_ID) notes from (
        select "Table", mat_ID, note_id from test where "Table"='A' order by ID desc  )t1
    group by "Table", mat_ID ) ta
join (
    select "Table", mat_ID, group_concat(Note_ID) notes from (
        select "Table", mat_ID, note_id from test where "Table"='B' order by ID desc  )t2
    group by "Table", mat_ID )tb on ta.notes=tb.notes 
join MaterialA on ta.mat_id=MaterialA.ID
```

Comment: I just tried this with inverted Order (4   Gold    5, 4) than I just get concrete as result. ORDER BY within group_concat() does not work for SQLite. any other options?